# Magento 2 - Add merchantDescriptor to Authorize.net Request

Tags: magento, magento2, authorize.net

I have a magento 2.1.9 instance that will have 5 stores running on it. What I need to do is edit the authorize.net request being sent from each store so that it passes Authorize.net's `merchantDescriptor` field. I need to do this so that the customer will see the name of the store they purchased from instead of the parent companies business name on their credit card statement. I really don't know enough about how magento handles Authorize.net to even gauge a starting point. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.